# Haskell type is too permissive: need to apply continuation at most once

Tags: haskell, types, dependent-type

Suppose I have the following type:

```hs
type Control a = (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

I want exactly two values to inhabit this type when universally quantified:

```hs
break :: Control a
break = const id

continue :: Control a
continue = id
```

However, the astute amongst you would notice that `Control a` is the type of [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals), of which there are infinitely many. Is there any way to restrict this type so that the continuation can be applied at most once? Perhaps using dependent types?

---

Note that `Control` can appear in the context of a bigger function. For example:

```hs
mult :: Int -> Control Int
mult 0 = \k a -> k 0
mult b = \k a -> k (b * a)
```

As you can see `\k a -> k (b * a)` is neither `break` nor `continue` but is still a valid inhabitant of `Control`. However, it's not an inhabitant of `Control a`. It's an inhabitant of `Control Int`.

Thus, what I'm really asking is whether there's a way to check that a continuation is applied at most once at the type level.

Comment: I never said that `Control` is the type of Church numerals. I said that `Control a` is the type of Church numerals. This was before the edit.

Comment: Do you want [linear types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructural_type_system)?

Comment: @chepner Not linear types, but from the same page you referenced I see that what I'm looking for are [affine types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructural_type_system#Affine_type_systems).

Comment: @AaditMShah Yeah, after I posted it, I remembered affine types are the "at most once" version instead of "exactly once". Linear types are just the ones getting all the attention lately :)

Comment: If you want linear types and are using Haskell, you may be interested in the following very recent GHC extension: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/LinearTypes

Comment: That extension does not (currently) appear to support affine types though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may recognize that `const id` is Church zero, and `id` is Church one, so we need Church naturals less than two - but if you want a two-element type, why not use `Bool`? Then interpret `True` as `const id` and `False` as `id`, or the other way. We can also say that `Control a` values are valid if they are in the image of the interpretation.

All types with two inhabitants are isomorphic, so if you restrict `Control` (which you could do with some dependent types), that would be just isomorphic to `Bool`. It makes more sense to define subsets of types when there isn't a compact standalone characterization of the subset.

Comment: True, but in my case I want `Control a` to be `(a -> a) -> a -> a` because it's used in the context of a bigger function `reduce :: (b -> Control a) -> [b] -> a -> a; reduce f = foldr f id`. I could trivially define a new data type `data Control a = Break a | Continue a` and then define `reduce` as `reduce :: (b -> a -> Control a) -> [b] -> a -> a; reduce f [] a = a; reduce f (x:xs) a = case f x a of { Break a -> a; Continue a -> reduce f xs a }`. However, this is not as natural. Plus, I just want to know if there's a dependent type for the subset `{ 0, 1 }` of Church numerals.

Comment: @AaditMShah Just curious, if `Control` is restricted as you want, how would `reduce` be different from `\_ _ -> id`? Your new definition of `Control` via `data` is very different from the old one, is it intentional?

Comment: `data Control = Break | Continue` would work more like you want.

Comment: @n.m. Good question. The `reduce` function behaves just like `foldl` but with early termination. For example, `reduce (\b -> if b == 0 then break else \k a -> k (b * a)) [1000,999..] 1` evaluates to `0`. As you can see, in the else branch I'm returning `\k a -> k (b * a)` which is neither `break` nor `continue`. However, it's valid because it uses the free variable `b` and only applies `k` once. Essentially, I want to restrict the type `(a -> a) -> a -> a)` in such a way that `(a -> a)` can only be applied at most once. Without free variables only `break` and `continue` are valid values.

Comment: @n.m. Perhaps my original question was lacking in details. I'll update it. Anyway, my new definition of `Control` isn't very different from the old one. Both `forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a` and `forall a. a -> Control a` have exactly two values. However they need to carry additional information which is why they are defined the way they are.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own ad hoc class for this:

```
class HasId p where
  theId :: p a a
instance HasId (->) where
  theId = id

type B = forall p a. HasId p => p a a -> p a a
```

This definitely shouldn't have any legitimate extra values.

Note that while `HasId` doesn't have any laws (and really can't have any), it admits exactly one instance for `(->)`, the only type we really care about.

[Edit: I have completely changed this answer a couple times as my ideas matured.]